# Can I have two two relationships on one field?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, web

I am creating a database which due to college security rules has to be an access database :( but its a website database and i have an invoiceing system. I have an user and product table and i am trying to add a comment table which relates to both of the these tables via the fields UID(user id) & PID(product id). however both of these field are already related to the invoice table. im sorry if this seems like a stupid question but i couldnt find a clear answer on this.

Comment: because of the college security rules. believe me i have argued this point but to no avail

Comment: Its quite unclear what you're asking here.  You have 2 tables, want to create another with two columns that are referenced in a 3rd table.  Ok, I'm not clear on what the problem is.  Perhaps a schema, or some example tables would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing saying that you can't have two tables that use the same foreign keys from two other tables.  But, you need to ask yourself what you are trying to represent.

Are you trying to make arbitrary comments about each user and each product, or are you really trying to attach comments to an invoice line?  If that is the case, then you should probably either put the comment in the Invoice table, or make a foreign key relations ship with that.

In the attached diagram I show both ways a Comments table could be related.[image]